# Display each checkbox in new line inside a div on asp page

Tags: c#

I have many checkboxes having text as substring from a long message. This I have done to select necessary strings from the long message and finally combined into required message , which I know how to do.

I want to know how to display these checkboxes , each in new line. How can i display them inside div , each checkbox in new line.

```
 string[] longMsg = str.Split('*'); //Message contains * character as delimiter


    for (int i = 0; i < longMsg.Length; i++)
    {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

        cb.Text = longMsg[i];
        Form.Controls.Add(cb);
    }
```

Right now on `Form.Controls.Add(cb)` results in displaying them in serial manner . Please help what should I do on **aspx** page and **.cs** page. Thanks , need your help ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
string[] longMsg = str.Split('*'); //Message contains * character as delimiter


for (int i = 0; i < longMsg.Length; i++)
{
  CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
  cb.Text = longMsg[i];

  Literal br = new Literal();
  br.Text = "<br/>";

  Form.Controls.Add(cb);
  Form.Controls.Add(br );
}
```

Comment: I tell you sir , you are Magnificent , I am good as nothing without wonderful guys like you from StackOverflow. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

After Every control is added, add  a `<br />`

as

```
Form.Controls.Add(cb);
```

add the following after the above line

```
Form.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
```

Answer (score 1):

JUST DO THIS:-

```
string[] longMsg = str.Split('*'); //Message contains * character as delimiter


    for (int i = 0; i < longMsg.Length; i++)
    {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

        cb.Text = longMsg[i];
        Form.Controls.Add(cb);
        Form.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));

    }
```